Kodaira dimension
Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve over an algebraic field $k$. I suppose the Kodaira dimension of $C$ is $0$. Why the genus must be $1$?
If $C$ is a smooth projective surface, and if I suppose the Kodaira dimension is $0$ why $dim_{k}(H^{0}(C, nK_{C})) \leq 1$ for all $n$ and is equal to $1$ for some $n$? Here $K_{C}$ is the canonical sheaf.

For the most useful answer, please specify which definition of Kodaira dimension you use.

Hi, OK. If $K$ is the canonical divisor, each divisor $nK$ defines a rationnal map $\phi_{n} : C -->\mathbb{P}^{|nK|}$. Then, $\kappa(C) := sup_{n}dim(\phi_{n}(C))$.

If the dimension is at least 2, then it defines a map to the rational curve

Yes, but why is this map non constant? Why if I have a rational map $C -->\mathbb{P}^{r}$ $r \ge 2$ then it is non constant? Here, $C$ stills a curve or a surface (smooth and projective) over $k$.

this is simply by the definition of a "rational map defined by a linear system". The map is a constant only if the linear system has only fixed part (its movable part is trivial)

Indeed a rational map defined by a linear system without fixed part is sucht that its image isn't contained in any hyperplane. But why does $nK$ have not fixed part?
